# how many monsters do I need to kill to fight Last Ones

Tags: lightning-returns-final-fantasy-13

In the Datalog I can see where it shows how common a monster is however I want to know how many monsters I need to kill to make Last Ones appear. Is it a set number across all species or is it different?

Comment: It depends on the species. And there's a couple that don't have last ones.

Answer (score 2):

```
Gremlin # 100
Niblet  # 120
Zaltys  # 30
Cyclops # 30
Dreadnought # 30
Gaunt # 60
Zomok # 30
Gorgonopsid # 80
Reaver # 30
Goblin # 80
Ectopudding # 60
Chocobo Eater # 30
Rafflesia # 100
Dryad # 80
Protoflorian # 30
Triffid # 80
Earth Eater # 30
Miniflan # 100
Hanuman/Vali # 100
Schrodinger # 80
Cactuar # 30
Gurangatch # 30
Hoplite # 80
Skatane # 80
Sahagin # 80
Meonekton # 65.563 (LoL)
Arcangeli # 30
Sugriva/Neela/Wendigo # 30
Chimera # 30
Skeleton # 60
Goblot # 100
```

[Source](http://www.ign.com/wikis/lightning-returns-final-fantasy-xiii/The_Last_Ones_%28Omega%29)

For faster gameplay you only need to kill only the big ones Omega Version.
They spawn very fast in the highway after you complete all "Roadworks"  Canvars of Prayer, and kill the rest in the Ultimate Lair.

And do not try to kill Meonekton Omega outside Ultimate Lair, just sayin is all.

Comment: do you know why Meonekton is a decimal number?

Comment: not decimal.You need to kill 65 THOUSAND Meonekton to spawn their Omega. I think they make it so many because it`s one of your Gil income besida Cactuar & Big Ones (which you can only kill 30 times each until they extinct). Your best bet is just kill Meonekton Omega in the Ultimate Lair.